# INSTALL_REFERRER Intent not working in above 3.2 version

Tags: android

We developed an application based on INSTALL_REFERRER intent.
Our application tries to retrieve the utm parameters sent at the time
of installation from Google Play.
We are successfully able to receive the intent (with utm parameters)
on Android 2.3.5 device, but the same intent is not being received on
Android 3.2.* version devices.

The problem seems to be common on the blogs but we are not finding any
solution to fix it.

Is it the problem with Android 3.2.) version SDK?  Is the
INSTALL_REFERRER behavior changed?
If anyone has the solution to fix this issue, please share with us.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently something was changed in the Android 3.2 SDK, more specifically during an update. Like you pointed out, this problem does not seem to be localized. I have monitored the situation in the past week, and Google has been fairly silent as to why this has happened. However, seeing how many people this affected I wouldn't be surprised if this issue was fixed in the next update.

I seem to have found [a temporary workaround](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19247#c23) you could use. I have not tried it myself, so I do not know how it would work, but it seems pretty solid.